sed to parse compiler warning message
I am trying to use sed to grab file path, line number, compiler warning number and warning message but I am failing.
grep -E "C6001|C6011|C28197" release-log.txt |
head |
sed -r 's/^([a-zA-Z\\:.]+)\(([0-9]+)\) warning (C[0-9]+): (.+).(.+)$/(\3) \1:\2 \4/g'

C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kallocator.h(196): warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'Allocator'. : Lines: 189, 196 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Lease\KTransport\user\KTransport.user.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kstringview.proto.h(2505): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*Temp_value_#2479'.: Lines: 2493, 2492, 2496, 2505, 2506, 2505 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Lease\KTransport\user\KTransport.user.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kstringview.proto.h(2505): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*Temp_value_#2937'.: Lines: 2493, 2492, 2496, 2505, 2506, 2505 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Lease\KTransport\user\KTransport.user.vcxproj]
C:\.tools\CxCache\gmock.1.11.0\lib\native\src\gtest\src\gtest-port.cc(1003): warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'regex'. See line 996 for an earlier location where this can occur: Lines: 985, 986, 990, 991, 996, 1000, 1001, 1003 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\test\GoogleTest\lib\GoogleTest.vcxproj]
C:\.tools\CxCache\gmock.1.11.0\lib\native\src\gtest\src\gtest-port.cc(1004): warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'buffer'. : Lines: 985, 986, 990, 991, 996, 1000, 1001, 1003, 1004 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\test\GoogleTest\lib\GoogleTest.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\ktask.h(445): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'ResultSet'.: Lines: 439, 444, 445 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Lease\KTransport\user\KTransport.user.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kallocator.h(196): warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'Allocator'. : Lines: 189, 196 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\ktllogger\sys\tools\GetMBInfo\GetMBInfo.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kstringview.proto.h(2505): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*Temp_value_#2479'.: Lines: 2493, 2492, 2496, 2505, 2506, 2505 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\ktllogger\sys\tools\GetMBInfo\GetMBInfo.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kstringview.proto.h(2505): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory '*Temp_value_#2937'.: Lines: 2493, 2492, 2496, 2505, 2506, 2505 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\ktllogger\sys\tools\GetMBInfo\GetMBInfo.vcxproj]
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\ktask.h(445): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'ResultSet'.: Lines: 439, 444, 445 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\ktllogger\sys\tools\GetMBInfo\GetMBInfo.vcxproj

For example, given:
C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kallocator.h(196): warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'Allocator'. : Lines: 189, 196 [C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\src\Lease\KTransport\user\KTransport.user.vcxproj]

I want:
(C6011) C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kallocator.h:196 Dereferencing NULL pointer 'Allocator'


Why do you want to use sed? I think that would be easier with awk.

@kzi can you please show me how to do it using awk?

@Node.JS I already figured out how to do it with sed, see my answer below ;)

@Node.JS: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Your specification contains several aspects that significantly increase the complexity. Do you really insist on replacing (196) (line number) with :196? Do you really want to suppress the final period , if any, in the message? And please, show the exact output you want for all lines (there are various formats and you show what you want for only one of them).

This job is much easier with awk. You may use:
awk -F ': ' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/.* /, "", $2); print "(" $2 ")", $1, $3}' release-log.txt

(C6011) C:\WindowsFabric\src\prod\ktl\src\inc\kallocator.h(196) Dereferencing NULL pointer 'Allocator'.


Indeed, it is an easier solution!

This works, assuming all lines are structured like your example lines.
sed -r "s/^(C:[^(]+)[(](.+)[)]: warning ([^:]+):(.+').*/(\3) \1:\2\4/" yourFile.txt

You may not use a file as input, but just pipe stdout from your previous command to sed as you probably know.
Explanation:
First Group: From including C: to before the ( char, assuming there is always a number (or other characters) in parentheses after the path.
Second Group: What's surrounded by parentheses
Third Group: The name of the warning (from after "warning " to one character before :).
Fourth Group: From after : to and including the last ' character in the line (because it's greedy by default)
Useful additional info: The g at the end of a substitution-statement in sed means: Do the substitution multiple times per line if possible. When you know that the substitution can only happen once per line (or even want it to only happen once per line), you don't have to add it.

sed -nE 's/(.*)\(([0-9]+)\): warning ([^:]*): (.*): Lines:.*/(\3) \1:\2 \4/p'

